# Admin and user Login page redirect

Tags: php

i want to have a static user in the database as admin and password admin for the administrator but the rest of the users it will using different users and password from the database,this is my script

```
<?php
mysql_select_db('billdb',mysql_connect('localhost','root','test'))or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

        //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    $fname = ($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = ($_POST['lname']);

        //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);


if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $member['password'];
            $_SESSION['fname'] = $member['fname'];
            $_SESSION['lname'] = $member['lname'];


            session_write_close();
            header("location: homepage.php?");
            exit();
            }

        else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login_error.php");
            exit();
        }
        }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }   


?>
```

i want to do a page redirect if its a different user it should go to `homepage1.php` but if its admin it should go to `homepage.php`

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! ***SQL Injection!*** *It's not just for breakfast any more!*

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: If you get something back from the database, like a variable which is equal to 'admin', you can test it and use it for the redirect.

Comment: **Never store passwords in the SESSION array!** Why would you need to even do that? Are you planning to perform another login with the information?

Comment: all the users are stored on one table?

Comment: @JayBlanchard why not store password in session?

Comment: Because you do not need it for anything and it exposes the password should someone hack the session @LorenceHernandez. In other words, *it's dangerous!*

Comment: @LorenceHernandez please visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594202/is-it-secure-to-store-a-password-in-a-session

Comment: @JayBlanchard i see, is that called a session hijack?

Comment: Yes @LorenceHernandez, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483092/php-session-hijacking

Comment: @JayBlanchard cool thanks il read it., i always think of storing it in session so when the user change their pass it saves the overhead of checking in database if the password they entered is matched. thanks too Masivuye Cokile

Comment: @JayBlanchard web is not really my native thing,  i should really read some stuffs about best practices

Comment: Apparently you are using a whole new table for the admins. You could just add a column to your users table called: `admin` or `role` or something. 0= normal user. 1= admin

Comment: You could store the hash of the password in a session variable if you wanted to @LorenceHernandez and check it with `password_verify()` if you wanted to save a round trip to the database but honestly, a you're not saving much.

Comment: thanks for that :) i solved my problem before the creator of this thread lol

Answer (score 1):

I have supplied a lot of warnings you should heed in the comments under your question but wanted to answer your question about redirects. Assuming there is a field called admin in your table and the value for an admin is 'admin' you can do the following:

```
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
        //Login Successful
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if('admin' == $member['admin']) { // some way of identifying an admin
            // admin
            header("location: homepage.php?");
            exit;
        } else {
            // user
            header("location: homepage1.php?");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding OP's question or OP's database structure is not like this. He has a new table called 'admin' so when there is no admin found with that username or password, he wont go through the `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){` anyway. So it should just be: `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){ //admin }else{ //user } `. It's easy as that right?

Comment: I had to make some assumptions @Loko but you could be right as well since we have no idea of the structure of the OP's database.

Comment: For the sake of OP's structure and code, I hope I'm wrong but it doesnt look like it.

Comment: He is saying, " static user in the database as admin" and "rest of the users" which is why I went the direction I did.

Comment: He has this query though: `SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'` which makes me think his structure is the way that I'm thinking it is.

Comment: Yeah - it could be. We'll likely never know given this OP's track record.