# PHP session based login code logging SOME users out when navigating protected pages

Tags: php, authentication, session

Session-based protected content on my site. Users enter username/password. Code checks for a match and either grants access or shows an error message "try again, forgot password, etc"

This works, like 99.9% of time. Out of thousands of users, I have received tech reports on maybe 15, all reporting this same odd behavior:

- User enters credentials, there is a match and they are sent to their account portal. Portal has dozens of protected pages.
- User navigates from the account home page to another protected page, which also checks for assigned session variables before displaying protected content. If no match, displays login dialog.
- What I am seeing reported (even seen screen recordings from some users) is that they login successfully and click any internal link and are then shown the login screen again. Log back in, success. Click another link, log in screen, etc
  _ **Even odder:** for the handful, I have been able to change their password and don't experience the issue on their end. Furthermore, after resetting the password for them, the issue disappears.

To reiterate, this is occuring for a handful of users, most have intended user experience.

Could this literally be related to the content of the password? There's no injection going on, that's not the issue.

LOGIN PAGE:

```
session_start();

include 'access.php';

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;  

// redirect to account home page on successful login
header('Location: ../account');
exit; // redirect to account home page
```

ACCESS.PHP (LOGIN FORM)

```
require_once "../common/db.php"; // dbcon

$year = DATE("Y");

session_start();
$sid = session_id();

@$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : $_SESSION['username'];
@$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : $_SESSION['password'];

if(!isset($username)) { // SHOW LOGIN FORM
    exit;
} // end if

$username = htmlspecialchars($username);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$hashed = md5($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? and password=? AND status='1'"; // SQL with parameters
$stmt = $connection_mysql->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username,$hashed);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
$user = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch data   

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['password']); /// SHOW LOGIN ERROR MESSAGE 
    exit;

} // end if

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !==0)  {
    
    // update members to add sid for current session
    $datetime = DATE("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $update = "update users set sid='$sid', last_login='$datetime' where username='$user[username]' and password='$user[password]'";
    $update_result = mysqli_query($connection_mysql, $update);
    
    
    // get user info
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username='$user[username]' and password='$user[password]' and sid='$sid' AND status='1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection_mysql,$sql);
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch data
```

Finally, each page includes access.php before any browser output

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO questions must be about programming, please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you scaling your application horizontally? What session driver do you use?

Comment: Can I suggest you show us the code, we cannot help based on an essay

Comment: _"Could this literally be related to the content of the password?"_ Certainly, if the password contains a quote and you're not properly handling bound parameters and you're storing plain text passwords. _"There's no injection going on, that's not the issue."_ How do you know this? Show us the code.

Comment: "*There's no injection going on, that's not the issue*" I'm really not at all sure how you reached this conclusion. You have a pretty glaring injection vulnerability in `access.php`, as you've elected not to parameterize the queries where you update a user's `sid` and `last_login` values and instead have interpolated variables containing the user's username and password directly in your query string. For starters, a user with a password containing a `'` single quote character would indubitably break the expected functionality of this query.

Comment: Aside: it's also not clear why you even need the password as part of the `WHERE` conditions there; are your usernames not under a `UNIQUE` constraint in your data model that you need passwords to uniquely identify users? Why do you pull the user info *again* into `$user` after doing so once before in the same script?

Comment: High speed hashes like MD5 and SHA1 are considered broken for security purposes and are not sufficient for password hashing. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). See [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) for more details and [here](https://alexwebdevelop.com/php-password-hashing/) for a good tutorial.

Comment: You should also know [it's a less-than-stellar idea to keep plaintext passwords in session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594202/is-it-secure-to-store-a-password-in-a-session) (or anywhere), and nearly fully defeats the purpose of hashing them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` on input, that's not what it's for. Use it on output when you're displaying the userid. Never use it on password, since you should never be displaying that. What's probably happening here:

1. User enters a password with a character that would be changed by `htmlspecialchars()`, like `foo<bar`.
2. Your code changes that to `foo&lt;bar`.
3. If that matches the database, the include completes and the rest of the originating page runs. That page immediately stores the password in the session. However, it stores the post-processed value `foo&lt;bar`.
4. On next page load, you pull the password out of the session, which is now `foo&lt;bar`.
5. You run `htmlspecialchars()` again on that, and now you get `foo&amp;lt;bar`, which no longer matches your database, so the auth fails.

Lots of other problems here though:

- SQL injection. Use parameter binding for all queries.
- Don't use MD5.
- Don't use the password in your `WHERE` clause. Make sure your user identifier is unique, select the record for the matching user, and then validate that the passwords match.
- Don't store passwords in sessions. The existence of the session alone can be sufficient to prove that authentication happened.
- You're hitting the database three times for every page load. You can reduce this to once per login session.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help! I inherited this site, so I'm digging through a lot of stuff right now. All of the comments have helped!